# How do I rewrite the code to assign a random color to my sphere?

Tags: javascript, function, three.js

```
  function randomColor(){
    var randomcolor = new Color().setRGB(Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random());
    return{ randomcolor }
  };
  randomColor();
  var geometrySphere = new SphereGeometry(10, 15);
  var materialSphere = new MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: randomColor,
    flatShading: true,
    wireframe: true,
  });
  var meshSphere = new Mesh(geometrySphere, materialSphere);
  scene.add(meshSphere);
```

If I controll.log the color function it gives me a color, but it does not assign it to the cube.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the function itself as value for color, you should use the return value, and `Math.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1 so the color is going to be always black.

The code below should help:

```
  function randomColor(){
    var randomcolor = new Color().setRGB(Math.random() * 255, Math.random() * 255, Math.random() * 255);
    return{ randomcolor }
  };
  var color = randomColor();
  var geometrySphere = new SphereGeometry(10, 15);
  var materialSphere = new MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: color,
    flatShading: true,
    wireframe: true,
  });
  var meshSphere = new Mesh(geometrySphere, materialSphere);
  scene.add(meshSphere);
```